# Where to find more details about TF2.0 implementation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was used to TF 1.X and I'm currently exploring upgrading to TF2.0. My only issue is that I struggle to understand where stuff is defined in TF2.0. For instance in TF1.X it was relatively easy to understand where tensors where defined, where layers were defined and where the graph was defined, etc. In TF2.0, because of the interconnection with keras, I struggle to have the same understanding. Especially as in spyder, when I try to use the "go to object definition" it does not work for TF2.0.

Hence my two questions:

1. Do you have an idea why the "go to object definition" is not working? I use Windows, anaconda, spyder. I'm thining this might be due to the complicated new namespaces structure.
2. Is there any link that explains a bit more how things are implemented?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Spyder has a lot of issues in how it resolves imports. In some cases, it will allow for completely broken imports (`RotatingFileHandler` springs to mind) outside of Spyder, and it just becomes inexplicably broken on other systems. I've gone through every github issue thread I can find to resolve this with V3 and the official response is along the lines of "We don't know why this is broken, but we've changed it in V4". I wouldn't read too much into this functionality not working.

Comment: And while this isn't directly an import issue, I suspect that it's part of the same mechanism in how it looks up modules

Comment: Make sure you go through the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2) Note, that it will help you to link things better if you recognize the role keras plays in all this. keras in tensorflow is simply a *high level api*, and as such, may not necessarily expose everything that tensorflow had in tf1 at a low level, and *still has in tf2, outside the keras api*